# Bootstrap Navbar mobile view not collapsing properly

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have this bootstrap navbar not collapsing properly in the mobile view. Look at the image below.
[image]

Here is my code( it works well in jsfiddle) but in my angular project it doesn't work properly.
**JQuery 3.2.1** & **Bootstrap 3.3.7**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is also the angular-cli.json:

```
...
  "apps": [{
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
            "styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have already determined this on your own, but in case you haven't, your issue stems from trying to implement two different front-end frameworks. Contributors to the Materialize project on Github have stated, they

> do not support compatibility between multiple frontend frameworks.

You can see the GitHub question [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2382).

My guess is if you take out your references to Materialize in your .angular-cli.json file your navbar will work as you expect it to.`enter code here`